# Unable to ignore errors using psftp

Tags: error-handling, sftp, putty, mkdir, psftp

I wish to upload all files in `C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP` folder on my local Windows to a remote SFTP server's `myfolder` directory.

Below is my command:

```
C:\putty\psftp.exe -b C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt -l myuser -pw mypass 10.8.44.86
```

Here is my `C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt` file:

```
mkdir myfolder
cd myfolder
lcd "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP"
mput "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\SFTP\*.*"
```

Running the command gives the below permission denied error:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>C:\putty\psftp.exe -b C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt -l myuser -pw mypass 10.8.44.86
Using username "myuser".
Pre-authentication banner message from server:
| EFT Server Enterprise 7.3.2.8
End of banner message from server
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Remote working directory is /
mkdir /myfolder: permission denied
```

I then decided to ignore errors by using the `-be` argument to psftp. That does not work and I see the below error in output.

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>C:\putty\psftp.exe -be C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt -l myuser -pw mypass 10.8.44.86
PuTTY Secure File Transfer (SFTP) client
Release 0.73
Usage: psftp [options] [user@]host
Options:
  -V        print version information and exit
  -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
  -b file   use specified batchfile
  -bc       output batchfile commands
  -be       don't stop batchfile processing if errors
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -1 -2     force use of particular SSH protocol version
  -4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for user authentication
  -noagent  disable use of Pageant
  -agent    enable use of Pageant
  -hostkey aa:bb:cc:...
            manually specify a host key (may be repeated)
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
  -no-sanitise-stderr  don't strip control chars from standard error
  -proxycmd command
            use 'command' as local proxy
  -sshlog file
  -sshrawlog file
            log protocol details to a file

C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

The [`-be`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-option-be) and [`-b`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-option-b) are separate switches. So it should be:

```
psftp.exe -be -b C:\putty\sftp_commands.txt ...
```